# Python datetime: how to keep whole `us(microsecond)`?

Tags: python, datetime

```
In [25]: datetime.fromtimestamp(15179052980380002/10000000)
Out[25]: datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 6, 17, 21, 38, 38000)
```

As you can see here, it convert to `38000us` instead of `38002us` (`us` = microsecond)

How can I keep '2' of the right most digit?

Comment: There is a typo in your question, it should be `16` instead of `17`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a simple workaround of storing microseconds separately then [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) it into `datetime` object

```
>>> timestamp = 15179052980000000
>>> m_seconds = 38002
>>> dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp/10000000)
>>> dt
>>> datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 6, 16, 21, 38)
```

Then finally replace the `dt` with desired microseconds

```
>>> dt.replace(micorsecond=m_seconds)
>>> dt
>>> datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 6, 16, 21, 38, 38002)
```

Comment: Awesome answer ! :)

Comment: The OP does *not* have microseconds, they have nanoseconds.  If they had microseconds it would work just fine out of the box.

Answer (score 4):

You would need nanosecond precision to encode that value - note that you don't have .038002, you have 0.0380002 (extra digit).

This is 38000us (rounded), or 38000200ns.

Comment: How can I implement nanosecond precision?

Comment: @user3595632: You would need a custom type, `datetime` has microsecond precision.